# Functions composition commutativity

Tags: analysis, functions, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I have to prove that $\circ$ is not, in general, a commutative operation of Funct(X,X).

My approach:
Let X be a set, $a,b\in X$, $a\neq b$ constants. Let $i,j \in Funct(X,X)$ with $i:X \to X,\text{ } x \mapsto a \text{ and }j:X \to X,\text{ }x \mapsto b$. Suppose $\circ$ is a commutative operation on $Funct(X,X)$. Then $$(i\circ j) (x)=i(j(x))=a$$ and $$(j\circ i)(x)=j(i(x))=b.$$ If $(i\circ j)(x)=(j\circ i)(x)$ then $a=b$ which contradicts my assumption that $a\neq b$.

I am just learning to write proofs so I want to check if I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost right. The only questionable point is that you start with "Let $X$ be a set, $a,b \in X$, $a \neq b$". Some sets do not have two different elements that you can choose, for example if $X$ is empty, or $X$ is a singleton. Hence it's better to explicitly choose a set, for example $X = \{1,2\}$, and then you can explicitly choose two different elements, e.g. $a = 1$ and $b = 2$.

Modulo this, the rest of the proof is good. Some people could argue that proof by contradiction is not strictly necessary here (you can just compute $i \circ j$ and $j \circ i$ and see they aren't equal, hence composition is not commutative), but that's not very important.

Comment: It suffices to give a concrete example and the proof is done, right?

Comment: That's right, if you want to show that "statement $P$ is not true in general" all you need to do is show an explicit example where $P$ is false.

Comment: Thank you! I will take out the contradiction part and just show that $j\circ i \neq i\circ j$.